# Delete \n charater with Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a list of sentences which have this "\n" character.

```
[("Types of Third\n-\nParties\n"),("Examples of third\n-\nparties"), ...]
```

I tried with the following code :

```
def remove_whitespace(sent_text):    
    j=0
    for i in sent_text: 
        sent_text[j]=i.rstrip("\n")
        j+=1

 remove_whitespace(sent_text)
```

But the \n character didn't disappear.
Any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)? [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)?

Comment: i.replace("\n"," ")

Comment: @SmartManoj thakns, your method replace "\n" by a space , but I would like the delete it

Comment: Then `i.replace('\n','') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use list comprehension to remove these unwanted items.

```
input_list = [("Types of Third\n-\nParties\n"),("Examples of third\n-\nparties")]

def expunge_unwanted_elements(input_variable):
  cleaned =  [item.replace('\n', ' ').strip() for item in input_variable]

  # Do you want to remove the dashes?  If so use this one.
  # cleaned = [item.replace('\n', '').replace('-', ' ').strip() for item in input_variable]

  return cleaned


print (expunge_unwanted_elements(input_list))
# outputs 
['Types of Third - Parties', 'Examples of third - parties']

# or this output if you use the other cleaned in the function
['Types of Third Parties', 'Examples of third parties']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.split` & `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
data = [("Types of Third\n-\nParties\n"),("Examples of third\n-\nparties")]
for text in data:
    text = "".join(text.split("\n")) 
    print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
Types of Third-Parties
Examples of third-parties
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is using `str.replace`.
In your case:

```py
def remove_whitespace(sent_text):    
    j=0
    for i in sent_text: 
        sent_text[j]=i.replace("\n","")
        j+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rstrip() function.

If *text* is coming with \n or \r, *text.rstrip()* takes these off.